# Unable to filter out an element of a List for my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning FLutter and trying out stateful widgets such as sliders, lists, radio buttons and check boxes. I am trying to display a list of girls based on the following parameters:

- Distance
- Age
- Status
- Looking for

When the list is sorted by *distance* and I click on Is Serious, one of the girls: Monica, appears, when in fact she shouldn't as her *looking for* is **casual**.

[image]

Similarly, when the list is sorted by *age* and I click on Is Single, one of the girls: Reshmita appears, when in fact she shouldn't as her *status* is **married**.

[image]

**The following is my code**:

*girls.dart*

```
class Girls {
  String name;
  int distance;
  int age;
  String status;
  String lookingFor;

  Girls(this.name, this.distance, this.age, this.status, this.lookingFor);
}
```

*girls.screen.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/model/girls.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/gender.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/screens/selected_girl_details.dart';

class GirlsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GirlsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GirlsScreen> createState() => _GirlsScreenState();
}

class _GirlsScreenState extends State<GirlsScreen> {
  int distance = 15;
  int age = 25;
  String sortCriterion = "distance";
  bool isSingle = false;
  bool isSerious = false;

  void changeDistance(double num) {
    setState(() {
      distance = num.round();

      populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
      //this.filteredGirls = filteredGirls;
    });
  }

  void changeAgeLimit(double a) {
    setState(() {
      age = a.round();
      populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
    });
  }

  List<Girls> allGirls = [
    Girls("Reshmita", 25, 33, "Married", "Serious"),
    Girls("Ankita", 17, 26, "Single", "Serious"),
    Girls("Rupali", 42, 28, "Single", "Casual"),
    Girls("Monica", 50, 24, "Single", "Casual"),
    Girls("Sakshi", 9, 27, "Married", "Casual"),
  ];

  List<Girls> filteredGirlsbyDistance = [];
  List<Girls> filteredGirlsbyAge = [];
  List<Girls> filteredGirls = [];
  //List<Girls> filteredGirlsbySerious = [];
  //List<Girls> filteredGirlsbySingle = [];

  String selectedGirlName = "";
  int? selectedGirlDistance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //filteredGirls = allGirls;
    distance = 20;
    age = 28;
    sortCriterion = "distance";
    isSingle = false;
    isSerious = false;

    (sortCriterion == "distance")
        ? allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance))
        : allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.age.compareTo(b.age));
    populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
  }

  void populateFilteredGirls(int dis, int ag) {
    filteredGirlsbyDistance.clear();
    filteredGirlsbyAge.clear();
    filteredGirls.clear();
    //int len = filteredGirls.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < allGirls.length; i++) {
      if (allGirls[i].distance <= dis) {
        filteredGirlsbyDistance.add(allGirls[i]);
      }
    }
    filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbyDistance;
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
      if (filteredGirls[i].age <= ag) {
        filteredGirlsbyAge.add(filteredGirls[i]);
      }
    }
    filteredGirls = filteredGirlsbyAge;
    //len = filteredGirls.length;
    if (isSingle == true) {
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
        if (filteredGirls[i].status.toLowerCase() != "single") {
          filteredGirls.remove(filteredGirls[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    if (isSerious == true) {
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
        if (filteredGirls[i].lookingFor.toLowerCase() != "serious") {
          filteredGirls.remove(filteredGirls[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    //filteredGirls = filteredGirls.toSet().toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          // ElevatedButton(
          //     onPressed: () {
          //       Navigator.push(context,
          //           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GenderScreen()));
          //     },
          //     child: Text("Go to Gender Screen")),
          // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(30)),
          Text("Set max distance"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Slider(
            min: 1.0,
            max: 100.0,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set distance value',
            value: distance.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeDistance(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Current distance is $distance kms"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Set max age"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Slider(
            min: 18.0,
            max: 60.0,
            divisions: 42,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set age limit',
            value: age.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeAgeLimit(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Age limit is $age years"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Sort by:"),

          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.5)),
          ListTile(
            //minLeadingWidth: 30,
            title: Text("Age"),
            leading: Radio(
              value: "age",
              groupValue: sortCriterion,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sortCriterion = value.toString();
                  allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.age.compareTo(b.age));
                  populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.5)),
          ListTile(
            //minLeadingWidth: 30,
            title: Text("Distance"),
            leading: Radio(
              value: "distance",
              groupValue: sortCriterion,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  sortCriterion = value.toString();
                  allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
                  populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Is Single?"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5)),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isSingle = !isSingle;
                populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
              });
            },
            child: (isSingle == false)
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
                : Icon(Icons.check_box),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)),
          Text("Is Serious?"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.5)),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                isSerious = !isSerious;
                populateFilteredGirls(distance, age);
              });
            },
            child: (isSerious == false)
                ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
                : Icon(Icons.check_box),
          ),

          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteredGirls.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.girl_outlined),
                  trailing: Text("${filteredGirls[index].distance} km away"),
                  title: Text("${filteredGirls[index].name}"),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      "${filteredGirls[index].age} years old, ${filteredGirls[index].status}, ${filteredGirls[index].lookingFor}"),
                  onTap: () {
                    // setState(() {
                    //   selectedGirlName = filteredGirls[index].name;
                    //   selectedGirlDistance = filteredGirls[index].distance;
                    // });
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SelectedGirlDetails(
                                  girl: filteredGirls[index],
                                )));
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          //Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(25)),
          //ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Check girl's details")),
          // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          // Text("Selected girl is: $selectedGirlName"),
          // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          // Text("$selectedGirlName is $selectedGirlDistance km away"),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

What is the error with my code and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check this loop carefully, Our looping will work **`i < filteredGirls.length`**

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredGirls.length; i++) {
  final x = filteredGirls[i].lookingFor.toLowerCase() != "serious";
  if (x) {
    filteredGirls.remove(filteredGirls[i]);
  }
}
```

Now for the first-case. We have three girls on filteredGirls.

```
i => 0;
filteredGirls.length => 3
```

First girl is Anika and she is serious and doesn't remove list

```
i => 1;
filteredGirls.length => 3
```

Now if Rupali is not serious we are removing the girl from filteredGirls.

```
i => 2;  
filteredGirls.length => 2
```

> i < filteredGirls.length  breaks here

Now  notice our initial list length was 3 and promised to loop  on `i < filteredGirls.length`. After removing a single item, filteredGirls.length becomes 2. And loop breaks. And Monika stay on filter list.

To handle cases like this, create another list and store removable item, end of the loop remove items.  And I prefer using like below and change others filter logic in this pattern.

```dart
if (isSerious == true) {
  List<Girls> removable = [];
  for (final g in filteredGirls) {
    if (g.lookingFor.toLowerCase() != "serious") {
      removable.add(g);
    }
  }
  for (final g in removable) {
    filteredGirls.remove(g);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did end up using extra space and variables to store the filtered results for `status` and `lookingFor`.

From a space complexity point of view I was trying to avoid using any auxilary lists.

Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single query

```dart
List<Girls> filteredGirls = allGirls.where((element)=> element.age < 20 && element.distance < 10).toList();
```